# Drupal 8 User based Node Saving

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-8

I have two roles in Drupal 8 as Editor, Manager. An Editor can add nodes as unpublished and a Manager can review the nodes and approve/publish them in website.

For administration I am using default SEVEN theme for adding/editing nodes. How can I hide "Save and Publish" button to Editor role only?

Can it possibly by calling a template hook `node_presave`? I tried below code but doesn't work.

```
function seven_node_presave($node) {
    global $user;

    if (in_array('editor',$user->roles)){
        $node->status = FALSE;
    }
}
```

Can anyone suggest a solution for this?

Comment: Probably better asked on [Drupal Answers](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Have you looked at Workflow (https://www.drupal.org/project/workflow) or Override Node Options. What you are describing should be set within permissions. (https://www.drupal.org/project/override_node_options)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not the answer you are look are looking for but I found this really useful at my time:

Lightning Workflow - from Lightning distibution, stable and simple but if you already have started your project is less likely to fit in

Workflow - for D8 is still in beta but I have used it on D7, really powerful and manages things like your situation with no problems.